# Discord bot not starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

when i try to start my discord bot i get this error,I had even tried updating my node.js

pls go to this like to see error I am not able to post question including error https://athulrajtheno1.github.io/error/

here is the code if you want to look

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

const prefix = '~';

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is now online');// this sends a message to you in the console when the bot is online

    client.on('message', message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot)return;
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    });
});

client.login('i had given bot token');
```

Comment: All information for the question (including error messages) needs to be included in the question itself for the same reasons it shouldn't be posted as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

As transitioning from Discord.js version 12 to [Discord.js version 13](https://discord.js.org/) you now have to define the [intents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents) needed by your [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) to function.

You may define them like so:

```js
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: 513 }); // justifies the GUILDS and GUILD_MESSAGES intents
```

You may generate a suitable bitfield for the intents you need [here](https://ziad87.net/intents/).

Comment: granting all the intents is unnecessary and not needed API-spam. Please don't recommend this. The Intents are there to prevent exactly that.

Comment: My answer clearly states the user has to provide **suitable** intents and I have linked the [calculator](https://ziad87.net/intents/) for calculating a bitfield for the same , but since you seem concerned I'll go ahead and change them to GUILDS and GUILD_MESSAGES only

Comment: Also you don't have to generate a bitfield number, you can provide an array of intent flags (which is way more readable imo) but it's ur choice